# change field datatype in Cosmos DB

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a field in Cosmos DB which is mapped as an `number`, but it should be a `string`. I'd like to alter the schema in-place without reloading the data, is this possible with a query in the same way it can be achieved in SQL?

```
ALTER TABLE EVENTS
MODIFY COLUMN eventAmount varchar;
```

Have consulted the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-reference) but they only reference simple SQL commands.

Comment: The field datatype is defined per document.

Comment: What happens when you add the field length and run that command?

Comment: careful: some databases delete the data in the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DocumentDB is schemaless. There is no structure defined outside documents themselves so each document has their own schema. If you want to enforce some documents follow a certain structure, then that must be enforced by yourself in your application logic.

So, this means you can not "alter schema" for collection to change data types.

What you can and should do, is to fix documents which you consider having wrong schema by updating them. Query docs where `eventAmount` is stored as JS number and save the document with the value stored as a corresponding javascript string instead.